# how to write multiple lines to a file using shell script?

Tags: shell, xml

I need to read data from a source and have to form a XML file using shell script. But first of all i don't know how to write multiple lines in a file using shell script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use output redirection

```
echo '<fruit>'    > foo.xml   # overwrites
echo ' <apple />' >> foo.xml  # appends
echo '</fruit>    >> foo.xml  # appends
```

Or use a "here document"

```
cat <<EndXML > foo.xml
<fruit>
 <apple />
</fruit>
EndXML
```

Better yet is to use a scripting/programming language that has support for XML. I like Perl and XML::LibXML but you may prefer something else.

Comment: Thank you, Output redirection works perfectly for me. But all the tags ends up in a same line <fruit> <apple/> </fruit>.

Comment: When i used the second solution 'here document', i cant able to open up the xml document. am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: @Vel: Yes, but I can't tell what you might be doing wrong without more information:  Are you typing the command on the command line? Did you use cut & paste? Do you get an error message? If so, what was the error message exactly?

Comment: No i didn't do the cut and paste & not using the command line. I am saving the file on a remote location for both the operations. When i tried to open the file or try copying the file from the remote location to my desktop, it says 'Error Occurred'. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, can you also clear me is it possible to apply stylesheets for XML and achieve entity escaping in shell scripting?

Comment: @Vel: I think you should ask about stylesheets and entity-escaping as a separate question. I suggest you provide plenty of detail about your operating system, tools and objectives.

Comment: Sure I will do it.

Answer (score 2):

The following creates a file named "file.txt" (or replaces the contents of the file if it already exists), and writes "foo" (without quotes) into it :

```
echo "foo" > file.txt
```

What you seem to look for is the following, **appending** the string "foo" (again, without quotes) in the file (and again, creating the file if it doesn't exist)

```
echo "foo" >> file.txt
```

So the following code will write three lines to "file.txt":

```
echo "foo" >> file.txt ; echo "bar" >> file.txt; echo "beer" >> file.txt
```